# How to remove data after certain characters

Tags: r, tidyverse

I need to know how to remove all characters from a value after the first D letter and 1st number or 2 second number. I am not sure how to start.

I have a data frame and I have a column of type Character

- The column is called " Eircode "

The postal codes go from D01 to D24 ( these are Dublin postal codes )

The values are inputted like so
[What you see in red is what needs to be removed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHpE6.png)

I need to be able to remove the characters after the last digit.

My dataframe is called "MainSchools"

**So if the " Eircode " is `D03P820`, I need to have it as `D03` after my change.**

I would preferably like to be able to do this with the `Tidyverse` package if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please read and incorporate elements from [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Especially the aspects of using `dput()` for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `sub` here:

```r
df <- data.frame(Eircode=c("D15P820", "K78YD27", "D03P820"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$Eircode <- sub("^(D(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])).*$", "\\1", df$Eircode)
df

  Eircode
1     D15
2 K78YD27
3     D03
```

The regex pattern used above matches and captures Dublin postal codes as follows:

```regex
D           match D
(?:
    0[1-9]  followed by 0-9
    |       OR
    1[0-9]  10-19
    |       OR
    2[0-4]  20-24
)
```

Then, we use `\1` as the replacement in `sub`, leaving behind only the 3 character Dublin postal code.

Comment: I tried the above code and it worked exactly like expected . 
Thank you .
I also have values like `D6WHP92` which do not have the D06 format .
How can I tailor the above to suit this requirement also?

Comment: Maybe use: `^(D(?:[0-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])).*$` ... assuming that you _do_ want to target the value `D6WHP92`

Comment: For values such as `A94FC44` or `K32VK33` essentially anything that is not D( plus the number )
I know I can sub them manually but what quick function can I use to simply delete any values that are not in my D01 / D1 format ?

Comment: Use the above regex pattern with `grepl`.  You should open a new question at this point.

Comment: `MainSchools$Eircode <- sub("^(K).*$", "", MainSchools$Eircode)`
Just done this as I plan on subbing empty fields with something else.
Thanks for the help above.

Comment: To clarify the format, eircodes are always a letter, two digits, a space, and then four alphanumeric characters. The first three characters are the routing key. Routing keys beginning with `D` encode the historic Dublin postal districts. There is a single exception from the pattern with the routing key `D6W`, which exists for historical purposes (it's the old Dublin 6 West postal district). The space should be omitted in stored values, but inserted for display.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the stringr package for such operations.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sitrngr)

df %>% mutate(Eircode = str_extract_all(Eircode, '^[A-Z][0-9]{2}'))
```

**output** with the data from @Tim Biegeleisen:

```
  Eircode
1     D15
2     K78
3     D03
```

Comment: This is also a nice solution that works! Thank you

Comment: I am glad it works. Please consider upvoting whenever you gain upvoting privileges

Comment: An eircode is always a letter, two digits, (space), then four alphanumeric characters *except for* those beginning `D6W` @mrwahl. You'd need to adapt this code to allow for the `D6W` special case. (These exist for historical reasons.)